# NEO4j, Storing more than `3` models in the catalog is available with a licensed Graph Data Science library

Tags: neo4j

I am using NEO4j to do graph embedding. [This](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/machine-learning/node-embeddings/graph-sage/) is the document I follow. When I am running the code in Neo4j.

```
CALL gds.beta.graphSage.train(
  'noPropertiesGraph',
  {
    modelName: 'myModel',
    featureProperties: ['degree']
  }
)
YIELD trainMillis
RETURN trainMillis
```

I met this error. How do I solve this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph Data Science GDS library has its own separate license for its Enterprise Edition, which is not covered under Neo4j Enterprise Edition. You might wanna drop some of your older models to get this working.

Check this GitHub [discussion](https://github.com/neo4j/graph-data-science/issues/90).

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) Is there any solution to use the enterprise edition free? I am a student, would that be helpful?

Comment: You can try creating a neo4j sandbox online, here https://neo4j.com/sandbox/. But I don't think, it will help much. Deleting and updating modals is the only way

Comment: Thanks, may I ask, how to check the current number of the models and the info of each models?

Comment: I think this will help. https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/model-catalog/list/

Comment: Also this https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/model-catalog/#model-catalog-ops